# In logic, what does it mean when it says "$\Phi, \phi, \neg\psi$ is inconsistent"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Does it mean $\Phi, \phi$ is inconsistent and $\Phi,\neg\psi$ are inconsistent?

Comment: You should include more context about how this came up. Likely it means that all three of the statements together are inconsistent, and there's probably an implied idea that they are pairwise consistent.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Hello, thank you for taking the time to reply. I meant that $\Phi$ is a set of formulas with hypotheses $\phi$ and $\neg\psi$, and this entire thing is inconsistent. I am just trying to show that this implies that $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$. Does it mean that $\phi \wedge \neg\psi$ is false?

Comment: Example: Let $\Phi = \{ \lnot \phi \}$; then $\Phi, \phi$ is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that $\Phi, \phi, \lnot \psi$ is *inconsistent*, means that :

> $\Phi, \phi, \lnot \psi \vdash \bot$,

where $\bot$ means a contradiction.

Thus, we have : $\Phi, \phi \vdash \psi$, and we can conclude, by [implication introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof), with :

> > $\Phi \vdash \phi \to \psi$.